# Pseudo-classes after a class selector?

Tags: css, css-selectors, pseudo-class

I've got a class

```
    .text2{
    font-size: 1.2em;
    color: #473f37;
    padding-bottom: 0.3em;
    }
```

I want text of links to appear white within this class, how do I do it?

```
<div class="text2">
  <a href="notice">Notices</a>
</div>
```

I tried the below and it not working

```
.text2 a:link{
    color: white;
}
```

Comment: Is this a trick question? And what would you need a pseudo-selector for? Can you provide some markup?

Comment: no trick question, i'll update the question to have my markup

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
.text2 a { color: #ffffff; }
```

Comment: thanks but, don't I need the 'link' part below?

text2 a:link { color: #ffffff; }

anyway, with or without 'link', it's not working for me.

Comment: No, unless you were specifying a separate colour for the different link states; then you'd need a rule for a:link, a:hover, a:visited and a:active. The fact that it's not working sounds like a specificity issue to me - think about where else in your CSS you are specifying link colours (which could be overriding it).